# Get a VR app to be recognized as "Cardboard Compatible"

Tags: android, google-play, google-cardboard

I published a VR app on the store, and despite I'm using the Cardboard SDK (version 0.5.2, with an update to 0.5.3 on the way) and the app itself seems to do decently for itself, It doesn't appear in the list of "other Cardboard installed app" in the Cardboard Demo, and neither on the page:

["Apps for Cardboard" on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/promotion_3001011_cardboard_featured_apps?hl=it)

Is there some flag to turn on on the app manifest or some kind of voodoo to get an app listed as "cardbaord compatible"? Is the list picked by a team of reviewer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that you missing to specify the category `com.google.intent.category.CARDBOARD` in the`intent-filter` of your Main Activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

From the [Cardboard SDK documentation](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/get-started):

> The `intent-filter` and specifically
>   `com.google.intent.category.CARDBOARD` state that this activity is
>   compatible with Cardboard-like viewers. This category is used by the
>   [Cardboard
>   app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.samples.apps.cardboarddemo)
>   to list compatible apps installed on the user's phone.

Comment: They put *that piece of information* **in the sample**?!? You must be kidding me... Thank you: I would have never found it...

Comment: Technically, no.  It's in the section "Overview of the Code" which describes what a typical Java Cardboard app will look like.  It comes after the sample  app build-and-run instructions.

Comment: Correct, though I admit I expected more fanfare for a feature of that relevance...